# unity cloud build Post-Build Script upload to github pages

Tags: bash, git, unity-game-engine, github

I run my game on my Github pages.
and recently started using unity cloud builds.

I managed to get the post-build script running.
but have no clue on how to get it to pull the repository, apply the new build, and push it to GitHub.

So far I have tried this script, without much luck

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x

ssh-agent $(ssh-add ./id_rsa; git clone git@github.com:triktron/Road-Rage.git tmpResp; cp -r ./WebGL/Build ./tmpResp/;cd ./tmpResp/; git add Build; git commit -m "auto build"; git push)
```

the logs responded with this

```
2838: Executing Post-Build Script at upload.sh
2839: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
2840: @         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
2841: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
2842: It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
2843: This private key will be ignored.
2844: ++ git clone git@github.com:triktron/Road-Rage.git tmpResp
2845: Cloning into 'tmpResp'...
2846: ++ cp -r ./WebGL/Build ./tmpResp/
2847: cp: ./WebGL/Build: No such file or directory
2848: ++ cd ./tmpResp/
2849: ++ git add Build
2850: ++ git commit -m 'auto build'
2851: *** Please tell me who you are.
2852: Run
2853: to set your account's default identity.
2854: Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
2855: ++ git push
2856: Everything up-to-date
2857: + ssh-agent
2858: SSH_AGENT_PID=5387; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
2859: WORKSPACESIZE | ARTIFACTSSIZE
2860: --------------|--------------
2861: 154.10 MiB    | 12.79 MiB
```

thanks already for your time!

**[Update 23 march 2020]**
so i've spent more time on this then i'm willing to say but i figured it out.
here is my solution if anyone ever wants to do the same.

i placed this script in my files

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x

export buildfolder="$(find . -regex '.\/temp[^\/]*\/WebGL\/Build' -print -quit)"
if [ -z "$buildfolder" ]; then
  echo "Could not find build folder"
  exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d ./tmp ]; then
  git clone "https://${nickname}:${githubkey}@github.com/${nickname}/${repositorie}" ./tmp
fi
cp -r "$buildfolder" ./tmp
cd ./tmp
git add Build
git config --global user.email "$githubemail"
git config --global user.name "$nickname"
git commit -m "unity cloud build"
git push --force
```

and added these envirement varibles in my unity cloud build console
[picture of envirement vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUVMW.png)

Comment: How did you figure out where to search for the folder. I killed a whole day this doesn't work for me :D